# Retrieve just the like_count from the like_info of a Photo

Tags: facebook-fql

I would like to ask how to retrieve just the like_count from this query?

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20like_info%20FROM%20photo%20WHERE%20object_id=447876785249920
```

The result is

```
{"data": [
  {
     "like_info": {
        "can_like": false,
        "like_count": 2318,
        "user_likes": false
     }
  }
```

]
}

I just want to have the like_count for that particular photo.

Comment: Does it really matter that much? Just filter out the result in your code

Comment: I don't know how yet :( I'm just new in fql and I would like to filter it in jquery which also new to me. I just read last saturday.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in the query as:

```
1. SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()
2. SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id='PAGE_ID' AND uid IN (
    SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()
)
3. SELECT first_name, last_name, pic_big FROM USER WHERE uid IN(
    SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id='PAGE_ID' AND uid IN (
        SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()
    )
)
```

for more details here is the link:
http://www.leftjoin.net/2011/03/getting-list-of-user-friends-who-like-some-page/

Comment: I just want to get the like_count and pass it to some variable, it is a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

FQL query to select likes count

```
SELECT like_info.like_count FROM photo WHERE object_id='your photo id'
```